# optimize find duplicate values for data set in excess of 200,000

Tags: vba, optimization, duplicates

I am new to coding and need help with a code that won't complete.  I suspect it is due to the size of the data set.  I tested the code using a reduced data set and it processes fine.  However, my actual data set is over 210,000 rows and is expected to grow.
Is there a way to speed this up?  Thank you for your assistance

```
Sub DupValidation()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet

    Dim i As Long
    Dim lastrow As Long
    Dim lastrow2 As Long

    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    Set ws1 = wb.Worksheets("Tickets")

    lastrow = ws1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    ws1.Range("g2:g" & lastrow).ClearContents

    i = 2
    Do While i <= lastrow
        If Application.CountIf(ws1.Range(ws1.Cells(2, 2), ws1.Cells(lastrow, 2)), ws1.Cells(i, 2)) > 1 Then
            ws1.Cells(i, 7).Value = True
        End If
        i = i + 1
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: Look at doing this in memory with a `Variant` array perhaps.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO, this might be a better suited question for [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: BigBen.  I am a complete newbie.  Can you explain the Variant array you are suggesting?  Thank you

Answer (score 0):

May be better

```
Sub Check_Duplicates_Using_Evaluate()
    With Range("B2", Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
        .Offset(, 5).Value = .Parent.Evaluate("IF(COUNTIF(" & .Address & "," & .Address & ")>1,""True"","""")")
    End With
End Sub
```